# Powerpoint animation sequence based on random clicking

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

Ok, here's what I would like to do. The slide has a question listed at the top. The question has multiple answers below it that are initially invisible. I would like to ask the question and as people say answers click them to appear (fade-in, whatever.) I haven't found a way to do this that doesn't make me put the animations in a certain order. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of VBA can make this work, but working with invisible shapes is out ... if a shape is invisible, PPT won't let you select it, and you can't click it in slide show view.

One possibility is to use rectangles that contain the text you want to reveal; the rectangles can be any color you like, but after entering the text, make it the same color as the rectangles. Result: invisible text.

Then press Alt+F11 to open the VBA editor, insert a module and paste this into it:

```
Sub MakeVisible(oSh As Shape)
    With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End With
End Sub
```

Close the VBA editor, select each of your shape in turn and choose Insert | Action; give the shape a RUN MACRO action, with MakeInvisible as the macro.

Now when you start the show and click any of the shapes, it'll turn the text white so it's visible.

It'll save time to draw one rectangle to begin with, format it to taste, assign the macro action setting to it, then copy/paste it to make add'l shapes.